# How to check by click on AddToCart current product have an upsell or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce latest version in my eCommerce site.

But now I want to check on click `AddToCart` button current product have an upsell or not. If yes then `alert("Upsell available");` and if not then simple `AddToCart` action will be working and goto cart also.

I am not sure what is the condition here. And I also don't know which place need to make condition or which is better option for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in to your theme's `functions.php` :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_upsell_rohil_display', 15 );

if (!function_exists('custom_wc_upsell_rohil_display')) {
    function custom_wc_upsell_rohil_display() {
        global $product;
        $upsells = $product->get_upsells();
        if($upsells){
            wp_enqueue_script( 'frontend-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/frontend-custom.js', array("jquery"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now create one `.js` file and name it `frontend-custom.js` and save it in to `wp-content > themes > your current theme > js`.(So `js` would be stored in `wp-content > themes > your-current-theme > js > frontend-custom.js`) and add below code in that `js` file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".single_add_to_cart_button").click(function(){ 

        alert("Up sell available");

    });
});
```

That's it.Now when there is any upsell available to any product and user will click on **add to cart** button, an `alert` will pop up and then they will redirect to the cart.

**NOTE:** It will work only on `Single Product` page.

Comment: Hi @Rohil, can we possible after alert not going to woocommerce cart page?

Comment: So where would like to take them after alert ?

Comment: if have an upsells then it will not redirect to cart page after alert!

Comment: Make sure alert will be come after product is added to woocommerce cart!

Comment: What do you mean by open ?

Comment: So what basically do you want ? One time you are saying User should not redirect to Cart page and at the same time you are saying alert should come after product is added to the cart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68457/discussion-between-jatin-gadhiya-and-rohil-phpbeginner).

Comment: See @Rohil, if product is added to cart at that time we want to check product have an upsells or not. if it have then alert and after clicking ok then it will not redirect to cart page. it will be same page like product detail page.